# H2 socket timeout exception when trying to connect to H2 db

Tags: sockets, intellij-idea, h2

I have H2 db installed on the filesystem, the web application deployed in Tomcat connects to it using url:

```
jdbc:h2:${main.basedir}/target/h2/hsdb;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=true;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=8055
```

I also want to connect to the database from Intellij DB tool window, so I use

```
jdbc:h2:C:\.../target/h2/hsdb;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=true;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=2
```

**From time to time**, I get `SocketTimeoutException`s, hence I am unable to connect. It seems something is blocking socket or what not.

Previously, when I came across such issue, I found that there were problems with versions of H2 being used by the application and Intellij's version - they have to be in sync

As of now, versions are in sync:
[image: h2 versions in sync]

What could be causing `SocketTimeoutException`?
Is there anything wrong with my setup?

Note, I am using Windows